# Can't fill a form with post request

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make a bot that buys AMD products. Everything good, except for when I have to fill the information to complete the checkout.
Here's the code:

```
import requests
import bs4

s = requests.Session()
url1 = 'https://www.amd.com/en/direct-buy/add-to-cart/5450881600'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
while True:
    response = s.get(url1,headers=headers)
    x = response.status_code
    if x == 200:
        print("Found!")
        break
    elif x == 404:
       print("Not Found, retrying\n")
    elif x == 403:
       print("unauthorized, retrying\n")
    else:
       print("Unknown error...")
url = 'https://www.amd.com/en/direct-buy/checkout/payment/103861562413/it'


while True:
     post_params = {'email': "mymail", 'phone_number': "423435"}
     response = s.get(url,headers=headers)
     response = s.post(url, data=post_params,headers=headers)

#print(response.text)
```

some text boxes has "name" like email and phone number but others don't have it like the one for credit card number and cvc, I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You shouldn't retry on 400-499 errors, they are explicitly not retryable.

Comment: yeah but thats not the point :(

Comment: Are you sure the post request ONLY requires the form data + headers? No cookies, API key/session ID etc. I'd be surprised this is possible without a public API being provided

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow! 
I think what *might*  be helpful to you is something like Beautiful Soup, where you can grab elements via any attribute to interact with them. I realize you're just trying to pass in the data to map directly to the name, but you may have to adjust your approach. Good luck!

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/